# How to export svg or pdf from bokeh plot in google colab?

Tags: pdf, svg, google-colaboratory, bokeh

Goal is to save svg-figure with bokeh in google colab.

I followend the docs at https://colab.research.google.com/github/bebi103a/bebi103a.github.io/blob/master/lessons/06/intro_to_plotting_with_bokeh.ipynb

Result: RuntimeError, s. details below

```
p = bokeh.plotting.figure(
    width=400,
    height=300,
    x_axis_label="confidence when correct",
    y_axis_label="confidence when incorrect",
)
p.circle(
    source=df, 
    x="confidence when correct", 
    y="confidence when incorrect"
)

p.output_backend = "svg"
bokeh.io.export_svgs(p, filename="insomniac_confidence_correct.svg")


Then there is an error:
RuntimeError: To use bokeh.io image export functions you need selenium ('conda install selenium' or 'pip install selenium')
```

Comment: The lesson you link states: *"To save to SVG, you first change the output backend to "svg" and then you can click the disk icon again, and you will get an SVG rendering of the plot. For it to work, though, you will need to have Google Chrome installed on your machine along with chromedriver. **(You also have to have Seleniun installed, which you should have done in Lesson 0.)**"* Are you saying you already did this, but it is still not working?

Comment: @bigreddot, I tried, but in vain.

Comment: I don't really use (or like) colab, so all I can suggest is to run Jupyter locally where you have better control over the Python environment.

Comment: The function call (export_svgs) does not work BUT one can get svg-image by clicking on "save button" in figure (s. bokeh tools) after setting p.output_backend = "svg".
Thanks @bigreddot for you fast help

Answer (score 2):

Example code exporting to SVG using Bokeh from Colab:

```
!pip install bokeh
!pip install google-colab-selenium

from bokeh.plotting import figure as Figure
from bokeh.io import export_svg
from google_colab_selenium import Chrome

example_figure = Figure()
example_figure.line(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[3, 5, 4])

webdriver = Chrome()
example_figure.output_backend = 'svg'
export_svg(example_figure, filename='example_figure.svg', webdriver=webdriver)
```

Bokeh expects a web browser to be available to create its figures. This can be a little tricky with how the virtual machine that runs the Colab instance is set up. You can manually install the correct browser packages on the virtual machine instance. Or, you can use something like the `google-colab-selenium` package to do the installation work for you. In the above code, `google-colab-selenium` provides its own installation of Chrome. The `bokeh` functions that expect a web browser let you pass which browser driver you want to use. So from there, you're just able to pass in the webdriver that `google-colab-selenium` provides.